# Include Visual C++ Runtime with Application

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, euler-math-toolbox

I switched from Visual C++ 2010 Express to Visual C++ 2012 Professional for my application (Euler Math Toolbox). To be compatible to XP, I use the 110-XP platform toolset from Update 1 of Visual C++ 2012.

In earlier versions, I added three DLL files MSV90*.dll in the program directory and a manifest for these.  Can I the same for Visual C++ 110? And which files would I need to include? And do I need a manifest? If so, where can I find one?

Comment: Include the [Visual C++ Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) with your application. Use the package installer to copy the files; do not copy them yourself. (Because you may accidentally overwrite a newer version with an older version.)

Comment: @RaymondChen - If I could upvote your comment 100 times I would. This is the best way to do it. Add it as an answer and I will upvote that.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: You don't use a manifest anymore, that was retired with VS2010.  Simply copying the DLLs into the same directory, along with your EXE is sufficient.  Also avoids Raymond's doomsday scenario as well as that installer failing because somebody has installed a newer version than yours as well as your app failing because it doesn't work with the newer version for some reason.  And consider building with /MT if this is just a single EXE so you don't need those DLLs at all.

Answer (score 5):

Summarizing my findings so far, there are four options:

1. Provide a link to the MS download page for the VC runtime.
2. Add an installer for the VC runtime to your installation.
3. Copy msvcr***.dll to your program directory.
4. Compile with static libraries.

All of these seem to work.

(1) or (2) obviously have the problem with different versions of the runtime. We need to trust Microsoft and the program developers to keep compatibility.

(3) has the problem that the dll you add must run on the target machine.

I decided use (4), because it works. To try this, set `/MT` in the C++ -> Code Generation properties for your project.

Comment: The problems you list for 1, 2, and 3 don't really make a lot of sense. For 1 and 2, maintaining compatibility is no burden because you compile the application's code to target a specific version of the CRT, so you know that they work together. Then you link to (or bundle) this version of the CRT—no compatibility problems. For 3, I don't even know what you mean by "the DLL you add must run on the target machine." That's not a problem either, the CRT runs just fine on all machines. If it doesn't, you have bigger problems. If you're worried about the cost of loading a DLL...don't.

Comment: For 1, you may be right, as long as all versions of the VC110 runtime are compatible. There are different versions, aren't there? For 2, the installer might be older than the current version, which is a problem. You are right about 3, if you pick the correct version for your program (ARM, 32bit or 64bit). I had troubles with this.

Comment: @Rene Any idea where to find these msvcr***.dll files on your option 3?